# Does all system calls execute in kernel mode?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, signals, system-calls

Title says it all :).

But, let me expand a particular case.

So, far I have studied system calls that all require some interaction from hardware (like read(), write() etc.) so it makes sense to switch to kernel mode before executing those system calls (**trap** instruction).

Signals as I understand is purely software constructs meaning they are not directly generated by hardware (unlike interrupts). I understand them to be a message passing mechanism between processes (either kernel-kernel, kernel-user or user-user processes).

**Kill** is a system call which is used to send signals to a process.  It does not interact with hardware directly. So why do we need to make costly switch to kernel mode for executing that system call? I have not found any evidence of "special" system calls which do not trap into kernel mode before starting execution. Hence, the question.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and no.

The original definition of a system call is/was a system support (OS) function that is called by a trap of some kind rather than a "normal" function call.  So by that definition, every system call requires a switch to kernel mode, as if it didn't it wouldn't be a system call (just a normal system library call).

Over time, the distinction between system calls and library calls has been blurred, as things that are/were traditionally implemented as system calls (such as getpid or gettimeofday) were implemented other ways -- generally by having some fixed data the kernel would set up (and perhaps occasionally modify) for every process.  On Linux, there is a concept of the "vdso" (virtual dynamic shared object) which is created for every user process for precisely this reason, and so some "system calls" are actually implemented as a normal call into this special memory space.

Even with this, the precise definition of which functions are system calls and which are not persists, as, for backwards compatibility, all system calls continue to be available via the trap/interrupt/syscall interface; it's just that those available in the vdso will generally never be called via the trap.  This allows very old Linux binaries compiled before the vdso existed to continue to work.

Comment: Kernel mode is there in hardware to protect against users using privileged instructions. e.g. processes are OS constructs. Hardware is unaware of process. Hardware can't protect against user using privileged instruction. Because there are none so far as software constructs are concerned. Os maintains process table in memory and process management is simply updating in-memory table (in crudest sense). Anyone can interact with memory. Only protection is provided is by virtual address space since a process is not aware about address space organisation of another process. Am I missing something?

Comment: Processes run in unprivileged mode, so they are "locked in" to their virtual address space -- they can only interact with memory that is mapped in and can't change those mappings.  So they never have access to the OS memory and process management tables, and need to make system calls to change any mapping in a controlled manner (the kernel verifies that nothing "fishy" is going on).

Comment: Making much more sense now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A signal is not a communications channel, it's more like a bonk on the head that gets your attention but carries no information itself.

The semantics of SIGKILL, SIGSTOP, and others are requests to the process scheduler, not the target thread itself, so entry into the kernel space is required.

Signals are delivered by the process scheduler just before a thread is scheduled.  This is why processes in uninterruptable sleep (D-state) cannot be removed if they never wake up; they never get scheduled so no signal can be delivered.

Comment: Signals do carry information: see `siginfo_t` in [`man 2 sigaction`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html).

Comment: Yup, I understand it is just a "bonk" on a head. But I am unable to understand how would switching to kernel mode help? If in fact some system calls do not switch to kernel mode, how are kernel data structures for them protected from user? Since, purely software constructs (like kill(), fork() etc.) does not use specialised hardware instructions that can be made previliged. They normally use user level instructions like loading from and writing to memory.

Comment: @RahulPatel Your user process cannot access the memory of a different process to deliver a signal.

Comment: J Sible mentioned siginfo_t from a sigaction.  Notice this is mostly just context information so the receiving process can decide whether to trust the signal notification enough to act on it.